# How to add type check & type inference for js project that has custom module loader

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, jsdoc

My company has an old big js project that has a not standard module loader implement (not commonjs or AMD). The module loader syntax likes

```
(function(){
// create module
var Support = $.createClass($NameSpace("Util.Date"));
}())

(function(){
// load module
var BaseModule = $L("module.BaseModule");
}())
```

In this case we can not use the 「jsDoc support in javascript」 of typescript.
We want our project has ability of reference module each other & has type checking.

In some case, we want jsDoc can declare global interface. so that we can delcare module in each file...

Comment: You can add overloads  for the `$L` function .. not sure about the definition of `$.createClass`. If `Support` has the type you want, the overload would look something like `function $L(moduleName:"module.BaseModule"): typeof Support`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yes， I have the same idea, but code like `function $L(moduleName:"module.BaseModule"): typeof Support`  can not declare global the type of `Support` or export it. it works in module it self, but can not reference in other files

Comment: if you don't have `import`/ `export` statements everything should be in the global namespace, so I am kind of surprised it does not work. Maybe adding some old school `///` references ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I have update my question。our module written in IIF, so I can not export  the class `Support` to make `typeof Support` works